# Align table rows having different number of columns

Tags: tables, alignment, columns, rows

I have a table like this one. And I want to center the highlighted parts within those columns, i.e., for rows 2 to 4, I want the first three columns to spread horizontally under the four columns under Model 1. For rows 5 to 6, I want the highlighted part to be centered under Model 2. Still, I want to keep the values right-aligned. Is it possible? The code I am using is below.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\caption{}\label{}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}
\hline\hline
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Model 1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Model 2}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Estimate} & \textbf{S.E.} & \textbf{p-value} & & \textbf{Estimate} & \textbf{S.E.} & \textbf{p-value} \\ \hline\hline
Time & -0.0108 & 0.0006 & \textless{}0.0001 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & -0.0106 & 0.0003 & \textless{}0.0001 \\
Age at baseline & -0.0045 & 0.0001 & \textless{}0.0001 & & -0.0108 & 0.0002 & \textless{}0.0001 \\ \hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Estimate} & \textbf{S.E.} & \textbf{p-value} & $\bm{\sigma}^2$& \textbf{Estimate} & \textbf{S.E.} & \\
Time & 0.0028 & 0.8561 & 1.4808 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{-8.7595} & 0.1770 & 0.0721 & \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Assuming that `\sigma^2`denotes "variance", how should a reader interpret a negative value for a variance?

Comment: I typed it wrong ‍♀️. However, this is just a visual example of what I want to do.

Comment: Is the `\sigma^2` column supposed to belong to the "Model 1" group or the "Model 2" group? Possibly both? Or neither?

Comment: @Mico It belongs to "Model 1" group. I wanted to center those 3 columns over the 4 columns below. I don't know how to explain it better 

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't repeat header rows, in part because doing so makes for a very cluttered appearance. I would also avoid needless **bold-facing** of cells. If people can't figure out what's the header material of a table without bold-facing that material, something's very wrong with the table's basic layout.

Conversely, I think it would be a good idea to align the numbers in the seven data columns on their respective decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % allow alignment on decimal markers
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small
\caption{Abc}\label{tab:abc}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\smallskip
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
     l d{2.4} d{1.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{1.4} d{2.4} }
\toprule
Variables
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Model 1} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model 2} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-8}
 & \mc{Estimate} & \mc{s.e.} & \mc{$p$-value} 
 & \mc{$\sigma^2$}
 & \mc{Estimate} & \mc{s.e.} & \mc{$p$-value} \\ 
\midrule
Time & -0.0108 & 0.0006 & {<}0.0001 & 
     & -0.0106 & 0.0003 & {<}0.0001 \\
Age at baseline 
     & -0.0045 & 0.0001 & {<}0.0001 &  
     & -0.0108 & 0.0002 & {<}0.0001 \\ 
\midrule
Time &  0.0028 & 0.8561 &    1.4808 
     & -8.7595 % <-- "sigma-squared"
     &  0.1770 & 0.0721 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be using that. However, I'll be dealing with more tables like this one, and I'll have more parameters than just $$\sigma^2$$ for Model 1. If I use this layout, the table will be too large for my page. So, I would still like to know how to center those 3 columns over a number of columns that sit below. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @adrimsvieira - My well-intentioned advice would be to not go down that route. The more one "adjusts" the column layout, the likelier it'll be that your readers get completely confused. Instead, do consider what exactly you're trying to achieve by showing so many digits, in all data columns. Incidenatlly, I'm an econometrician, and I will admit that I am *deeply suspicious* of any empirical work that produces coefficient estimates with t-stats of 45 and up.

Comment: @adrimsvieira - If you're really concerned about running out of (horizontal) space, do ask yourself if it's truly necessary for the narrative of your paper that you're showing p-values. If this were my table and I were running out of space, the first columns I'd gladly give up are the p-value columns; to make up for this "loss" (hah), I'd mark the statistically significant coefficient estimates with, say, 1, 2, or 3 asterisks depending on whether the (now hidden) p-values are less than 0.1, 0.05, and 0.01, respectively.

Comment: Just adding to what Mico mentioned, I sure hope this is not your real data. "Deeply suspicious" is putting it mildly if a $p$-value of 1.4808 is given...

Comment: @Mico the values are not real. Thanks

Comment: @SteveKass the values are not real. My data is confidential, can't disclose them. But thanks anyway :)